# How to update SystemName from Get-WmiObject or update data table

Tags: powershell

I need to override SystemName from Get-WmiObject:

```
Function Get-VolumeSpace ([string]$ServerName="localhost") {
$wql="Select SystemName, Name, Capacity, FreeSpace From Win32_Volume Where (DriveType=2 or DriveType=3) and name like '[a-z]%'"
$volSpace=Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ServerName -Query $wql 
$volSpace | Select SystemName, Name, Capacity, FreeSpace}
```

On a SQL cluster, SystemName contains the physical node name and not the virtual name that I passed into Get-VolumeSpace.  I need it to be the name that I passed in and not the actual physical node name.

If I can override SystemName from within my Get-VolumeSpace function, that would be good.  Alternatively, I can just update the data table.  So I have put the output into a data table using Out-DataTable function that I found on the web:

```
$dataTable = Get-VolumeSpace $ServerName | Out-DataTable
```

Can someone either help me override SystemName with $ServerName in Get-VolumeSpace OR help me update the first column in every row to $ServerName in $dataTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you are asking, the following should work:

```
$volSpace | Select @{expression ={$ServerName};label="SystemName"}, Name, Capacity, FreeSpace
```